# how to test a REST web service that calls another SOAP web service in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am currently working on Spring Boot. I am stuck with a problem: My REST service is calling SOAP service and I want to unit test my service whether the XML response from SOAP service matches the REST service response in JSON.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Usually you do such things with mocking. During the test, you inject a class that behaves exactly like the target SOAP service, but is hardcoded to return some predetermined value. See [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) tutorial for example. In a nutshell, you tell Spring to inject a mocked bean into your service instead of the real one.

You can also mock the actual service, for example with something like [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/). In this case, you change the URL in Spring configuration to point to Wiremock instead of the actual service.